# Execute all files from a directory via terminal

Tags: command-line, files

I have tons of files in a directory and I need to select each one to import it. I don't know if I can execute all the files which are of the same extension and with different names each one via terminal.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a specific example of what you mean by "execute" and "import". Are the files themselves executable, or do you want to execute a *command on* each file?

Comment: I want to execute all the files from a directory, that files uses a ".osz" extension, i have like 1.000+ files that i need to execute like 14 by 14, and i think via terminal i can do that fastly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If they are already executable you can execute all of them with `find` and `-exec` with no commands

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -iname "*.osz" -exec '{}' \;
```